# JQuery OptGroup alpha sort

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following markup:-

```
<select name="List1" id="l1">
<option>One</option>
<option>Two</option>
<option>Three</option>
<option>Bob</option>
<option>Four</option>
<option>Five</option>
<option>Alyn</option>
</select>
```

And the following jquery:-

```
$('#l1 option:nth-child(n+5)').wrapAll('<optgroup label="Group 1">');
```

Which results in Four Five and Alyn appearing in an optgroup called Group 1.

I wish to sort the results alphabetically, but after the optgroup is applied.

So The first four results should be sorted alphabetically and the last 3 results within the optgroup should be sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/xGENn/16/

```
$('#sort').click(function() {

    var $options = $('#l1 option:nth-child(n+5)');
    $options.sort(function(a, b) {
        return $(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text());
    });
    $options.wrapAll('<optgroup label="Group 1">');

    $options = $('#l1').children('option');
    $options.sort(function(a, b) {
        return $(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text());
    });
    $('#l1').prepend($options).val($("#l1 option:first").val());
});

​
```

Comment: Works, but only for the optgroup. It needs to sort the options outside the optgroup too!

Comment: @generalexception you can apply the same logic to `$('#li select').children('option')` after the `optgroup` is applied, leave that as an exercise for you :)

Comment: should `$options = $('#li select').children('option');` be `#l1` and not `#li` ??

Comment: @generalexception ugh... sorry about that

Comment: Repeating the //sort using custom callback block after // do the rest doesent seem to work... am i missing something ?

Comment: @generalexception edited my answer, you could probably wrap the custom function in a function and then just pass it